# On the integral $\int\sqrt{1+\cos x}\text{d} x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've been wondering about the following integral recently:
$$
I = \int\sqrt{1+\cos x}\,\text{d}x
$$
The way I integrated it is I used the identity $\sqrt{1+\cos x} = \sqrt2\cos\frac x2$, and so
$$
I = 2\sqrt2\sin\frac x2 + C
$$

the problem is that $\sqrt{1+\cos x}$ is actually integrable over the entire real line, but the derivative of $2\sqrt2\sin\frac x2$ is only equal to $\sqrt{1+\cos x}$ in certain intervals. This is because the *actual* identity is $\sqrt{1+\cos x} = \sqrt2\left|\cos\frac x2\right|$. Now, I wasn't exactly sure how to integrate the absolute value, so I thought I would "fix" the function after integration.

The first fix we can do is making sure that the sign of the result of integration is correct:
$$
I = 2\sqrt2\sin\frac x2\text{sgn}\cos\frac x2 + C
$$
The problem with just $\sin\frac x2$ was that sometimes it was "flipped", on certain intervals it was actually the antiderivative of the $-\sqrt{1+\cos x}$ (this is because we dropped the absolute value signs).

There is one further problem with this, however. The above function is not continuous, meaning it's not continuously differentiable with derivative equal to $\sqrt{1+\cos x}$ everywhere. Namely, it is discontinuous at $x=(4n\pm1)\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I noticed, however, that the limit of the derivative on either side of $x=(4n\pm1)\pi$ existed and was equal to each other. Hence, I figured that I could somehow "stitch" these continuous sections end to end and get a continuous result whose derivative was $\sqrt{1+\cos x}$ everywhere. The resulting function I got was
$$
I = 2\sqrt2\sin\frac x2\text{sgn}\cos\frac x2 + 4\sqrt2\left\lfloor\frac1{2\pi}x+\frac12\right\rfloor + C
$$

Now, I was wondering, is there any way to arrive at this result just by integrating $\sqrt{1+\cos x}$ using the usual techniques? The method I used can be boiled down to "integrating" then "fixing", but I'm just wondering if you can arrive at a result that is continuous and differentiable on the entire real line by doing *just* the "integrating" part.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** To be clear, I'm not looking for *exactly* the function above, but rather simply any function that is "nice", continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, and has derivative equal to $\sqrt{1+\cos x}$ everywhere, and which is attainable through "simple" integration methods.

Comment: not at that *particular* result, but probably similar things

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt True, I'll update the question. I'm not looking for my specific result, but simply any "nice" result that satisfies the requirements.

Comment: NB: $\sqrt{1+\cos x}\ne\sqrt2\cos\frac x2$; rather, $\sqrt{1+\cos x}=\sqrt2\left|\cos\frac x2\right|$. For example, if $x=\frac{4\pi}3$, $\sqrt{1+\cos x}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ whereas $\sqrt2\cos\frac x2=-\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw Read the whole post please

Comment: My two cents:  Equation $\sqrt{1+\cos x} = \sqrt2\left|\cos\frac x2\right|$ is **NOT CORRECT** for complex numbers, and should be banned from use.

Comment: @GEdgar This is clearly meant over the real numbers. Why should complex numbers be considered? The integral would make no sense in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to be integrated is
$$
\sqrt{1+\cos x}=\sqrt{2}\left|\cos\frac{x}{2}\right|
$$
so we can as well consider the simpler
$$
\int\lvert\cos t\rvert\,dt
$$
or, with $t=u+\pi/2$, the even simpler
$$
\int|\sin u|\,du
$$
One antiderivative is
$$
\int_0^u\lvert\sin v\rvert\,dv
$$
Note that the function has period $\pi$, so let $u=k\pi+u_0$, with $0\le u_0<\pi$. Then
$$
\int_0^u\lvert\sin v\rvert\,dv=
\int_0^{k\pi}\lvert\sin v\rvert\,dv+
\int_{k\pi}^{k\pi+u_0}\lvert\sin v\rvert\,dv
\\=2k+\int_0^{u_0}\sin v\,dv=
2k+1-\cos(u-k\pi)
$$
Now do the back substitution; write $k=u\bmod\pi$, if you prefer.

Comment: Your first assumption is wrong: https://bit.ly/32YhYx9

Comment: @Rodrigo It is correct, we're working over the real numbers. The expression $\sqrt{1+\cos z}$ is not even well defined over the complex numbers.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha is an exceptional website developed by many experts in a lot of different fields, all of them work for Stephen Wolfram, the owner of the company, considered by many a genious, and you're saying that you know more than them.

Comment: @RodrigoSambade I don't know what the Wolfram company has to do with this. I computed correctly an antiderivative of the given function. By the way, if you scroll down the page you link you find https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zH07.png

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha says that the function is well defined over the complex numbers and, based on this, concludes that your first assumption is false.

Comment: @RodrigoSambade No, contrary to what you believe, the function is not well defined, because it has branch points where $\cos z=-1$. You can define it with values in a suitable Riemann surface, though, but in this case asking for an antiderivative is surely beyond the scope of the OP, who clearly asked about the real case (nobody in the world would use the integral sign for antiderivatives of a complex function).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you intended, but it follows geometrically due to the period of $\cos$ that

$$\int_0^x\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}\ dt=(x\text{ mod }2\pi)\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}\ dt+\int_0^{(x\text{ mod }2\pi)}\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}\ dt$$

That is, we really only need to take the integral for $x\in[0,2\pi)$ and we're set.  To do this, let $t=\arccos(u)$ with $x\in[0,2\pi)$.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^x\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}\ dt&=-\int_1^{\cos(x)}\sqrt{\frac{1+u}{1-u^2}}\ du\\&=\int_{\arccos(x)}^1\frac1{\sqrt{1-u}}\ du\\&=\left.-2\sqrt{1-u}\vphantom{\frac11}\right|_{\cos(x)}^1\\&=2\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}\end{align}$$

which reduces to yours via trig identities.  The extension to $x\ge2\pi$ via modular operations is also continuous, and the derivative is always $\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\int \sqrt{1+\cos(x)} dx = \int \frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}} dx
\end{equation}

Consider the substitution, $u=1+\cos(x)$. Then,

\begin{equation}
-\frac{du}{\sqrt{2u-u^2}}=dx
\end{equation}

Thus, the new equation in terms of $u$ will be

\begin{equation}
I= -\int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{2u-u^2}} du
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I= -\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{2-u}}
\end{equation}

With the substitution, $t=2-u$, we get

\begin{equation}
I=\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}
\end{equation}

By making substitutions for $t(u)$ and $u(x)$, the final answer becomes

\begin{equation}
I=2\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}+C.
\end{equation}

Multiplying and dividing by $\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}$ results in

\begin{equation}
\int \sqrt{1+\cos(x)} dx = \frac{2 \sqrt{{\sin}^2(x)}}{\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}}+C.
\end{equation}

However only when the term in numerator is taken to be $\sin(x)$ instead of absolute value of $\sin(x)$ the answer seems to be correct. The conclusion is drawn based on plotting the derivative of answer and comparing it with integrand.

Comment: $\sin^2 x =(1+\cos x) (1-\cos x)$.

Comment: Thank you Gary.